# Express Rate limiter not working with cluster load balancer node js

Tags: node.js, express, load-balancing, rate-limiting, express-rate-limit

I tried to use express rate limiter as follow:

```
require('express-rate-limit')({
    windowMs: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hrs in milliseconds
    max: 5,
    message: 'You have exceeded the 5 requests in 24 hrs limit!',
    standardHeaders: true,
    legacyHeaders: false,
})
```

It works fine but when i apply the cluster load balancer as like

```
if (cluster.isMaster) for (let i = 0; i < numCpus; i++) cluster.fork()
else shutdown(app.listen(PORT), mongoose)
```

It works fine unless the request gets handled by differnet process at any random moment.

It just doesn't work as expected. it's not blocking request based on the ip. Please help me or give me different solution for the rate limiter thanks

Comment: [_"This module does not share state with other processes/servers by default. If you need a more robust solution, I recommend using an external store"_](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit#alternate-rate-limiters)

Comment: @robertklep what do you prefer bro :)

Comment: `rate-limiter-flexible` package works in Cluster. Read more [here](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Cluster).

Comment: @Animir any idea about how do i setup multiple limiters? like one limiter for all requests another one for my otp requests?

Comment: Create several limiters and use them in different routes. [Here is an example](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Cluster#create-several-rate-limiters).

Comment: Try adding `app.set('trust proxy', numberOfProxies)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [@express-rate-limit/cluster-memory-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@express-rate-limit/cluster-memory-store) to synchronize hit counts between the workers when using express-rate-limit with node.js's built-in `cluster` module. (As long as you have only one server.)

Alternatively, any external [store](https://express-rate-limit.mintlify.app/reference/stores), such as the [mongodb store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limit-mongo), will also work to synchronize hits across your workers. This is the way to go if you have multiple servers.

---

Disclaimer: I'm the author of both express-rate-limit and @express-rate-limit/cluster-memory-store.